# HTML with latex code

Tags: pdftex, pdf, html, latex2html

I'm reading a HTML file, where math related stuffs are written in latex code.

It's just like:

> Let A be matrix and b be a vector. Then \|Ax - b\|_2^2 <= \epsilon is
>   what we need. Blah blah.

i.e. given bunch of phrases, they have latex syntaxis in the middle.

Is there any way to read this html file as a document with converted math symbol, rather than plane latex code, since it is cumbersome to interprete?

Comment: Hi @Schrödinger'scat . From your link, the thing seems to like a different type of (but similar) language to HTML. The thing is that in my case, I already have an HTML and I would like read it in a proper manner...

Comment: It seems like there are no download webpage and they are asking for membership or not...?

Comment: It was just a matter of Safari. As "Schrödinger's cat" suggested, it has mathML structure and NOT ALL BROWSERS are capable to read it properly. I changed my brouser to Chrome, from safari and now it perfrctly works. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, all I wanted to say is that this is not necessarily the right site for this question. Some of the other sites here do have something like MathJax and so on, which precisely supports the features you are seeking.